# Quotes in generated CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am generating CSV in my model, to respond with it as a file.

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate(col_sep: "\;") do |csv|
      csv << ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
      all.each do |record|
        csv << [record.date.to_s, record.text, (MessageCharacter.find_by_id(record.message_character_id).try(:name) || ""), record.commentable.name, record.user.name].map{|e| "#{e}"}
      end
    end
  end
```

As a result I'd like to have everything wrapped in quotes, something like:

```
"1";"2";"3";"4";"5"
"value1";"value2";"value3";"value4";"value5"
```

But instead I am getting either values without quotes (if in input data I don't wrap it in quotes), or if I wrap in extra quotes, I have each value with 3 quotes! So how do I wrap all values in way I show above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`force_quotes?()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-force_quotes-3F) you can use the `force_quotes` option like so:

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate(col_sep: "\;", force_quotes: true) do |csv|
      csv << ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
      all.each do |record|
        csv << [record.date.to_s, record.text, (MessageCharacter.find_by_id(record.message_character_id).try(:name) || ""), record.commentable.name, record.user.name].map{|e| "#{e}"}
      end
    end
  end
```

You can also specify the quotes you use with `quote_char: '"'` but double quote is the standard anyway.